# Update the field of the last array element to equal another field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of "sessions" (over 731,000 documents) which are structured like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  end_time: Date(164),
  members: [ 
    { user_id: "1", left_at: Date(73) },
    { user_id: "2", left_at: Date(0) }
 ]
}
```

I need to update all documents and set the last member's "left_at" field to equal the "end_time" field.

So based on the object above, the intended updated version should be:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  end_time: Date(164),
  members: [ 
    { user_id: "1", left_at: Date(73) },
    { user_id: "2", left_at: Date(164) }
 ]
}
```

NOTE:

- Assume that every session document has a `members` containing at least 1 element.
- To be more clear about the "last" member, I just mean index `members[members.length-1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      members: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $slice: [
              "$members",
              {
                $subtract: [ { $size: "$members" }, 1 ]
              }
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              user_id: { $last: "$members.user_id" },
              left_at: "$end_time"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LOVWsSqCRfB)